# Dealing with accuracy in Python math operations

Tags: python

I was trying to write a simple program to determine if input integer is a power of two.

I had following code. It will fail the test case for `n=536870912` (`536870912` is the `2^29`).

I tried with formating the number, `format(y,'12g')`    the output is close to `0` but not equal to `0`, `3.43965 e-07`.

How should I overcome this number issue?

```
    s= math.log(n,2)
    [sh,y]=divmod(s,1)

    if y!=0:
    #if format(yu,'20f')!=format(0,'20f') :
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: `math.log(536870912, 2)` = `29.000000000000004`

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/794749

Comment: `math.log` does not return an integer. It returns a floating point number. That's why your divmod doesn't give you the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare floats and allow for a little floating-point inaccuracy, you would normally check if they are within a certain allowable distance of each other (`if abs(x-y) < epsilon`).

However, if you want to find out if an *integer* is a power of 2, you can do it like this:

```
def ispoweroftwo(n):
    return (n>0 and (n&-n)==n)
```

This works according to the rules of [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation of signed numbers.

```
>>> ispoweroftwo(536870911)
False
>>> ispoweroftwo(536870912)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

The way to go about comparing floating point numbers for equality is `abs(a - b) < tolerance`, where `tolerance = 1e-6` or some similar small number. In your case it would just be `abs(y) < 1e-6`.

For more info check out [Accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) here or a popular [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

If you need accuracy and you don't want to reinvent the accuracy-wheel yourself, you could have a look at [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), which is precisely designed for this kind of purpose (accurately making complex mathematical operations on big numbers of any kind).

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2**4, 536870912])
np.log2(x)

# array([-Inf,   0.,   1.,   4., 29.])
```

See [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.log2.html) for `np.log2()` or a [quickstart tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html).