# wrong answer for large input

Tags: python, math

I am trying to determine whether an integer can be expressed in the form of a^b where b>1 and the given integer is greater than 0. My code runs fine for all test cases except for one.
It gives wrong answer for the following input:
536870912
I cant understand why.

```
 def isPower(self, A):
    if(A==1):
        return (1)
    for i in range(2,int(A**0.5)+1):
        val=log(A,i)
        if(int(val)-val==0):
            return (1)
    else:
        return (0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve:

```
from  math import log
def isPower(A):
    if(A==1):
        return (1)
    if (A&-A)==(A):
        return (1)        
    for i in range(2,int(A**0.5)+1):
        val=log(A,i)
        if(int(val)-val==0):
            return (1)
    else:
        return (0)
```

If you are looking for reason on why it is not working please refer the below link:

[Dealing with accuracy in Python math operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563797/dealing-with-accuracy-in-python-math-operations?rq=1)

Comment: thnx, it worked fine except for the case - '2' I added another elif condition to deal with this.

Comment: @AnantshreeChandola Also the above code returns 1 for the case '2' when you do isPower(2).